# React Router redirect IndexRoute to proper path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm trying to configure React Router so that when accessing http://url/manage/roomId it goes directly to http://url/manage/roomId/sessions (loading RoomSessions component). These are tabs components' routes and I want to load the first tab's content (which it does) by default with the proper URL (which it does not).

It works fine except for the redirection

```
<Route
    path="manage/:roomId"
    component={RoomsManagerManageRoom}
    onEnter={requireAuth}
>
    <IndexRoute component={RoomSessions} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="sessions" component={RoomSessions} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="meetings" component={RoomMeetings} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="files" component={RoomFiles} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="recordings" component={RoomRecordings} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="sections" component={RoomSections} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    <Route path="hosts" component={RoomHosts} onEnter={requireAuth} />
</Route>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you set up the redirect you're talking about?

Comment: nowhere, I want to know how

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace the `<IndexRoute />` line with

```
<IndexRedirect to="sessions" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to replace IndexRoute with IndexRedirect ... correct your answer and I will accept it.